# fs.createReadStream - limit the amount of data streamed at a time

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

If I only want to read 10 bytes at a time, or one line of data at a time (looking for newline characters) is it possible to pass fs.createReadStream() options like so

```
  var options = {}

  var stream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt', options);
```

so that I can limit the amount of data streamed at a time?
looking at the fs docs, I don't see any options that would allow me to do that even though I am guessing that it's possible.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: nevermind, it looks like 'highWaterMark' does the trick, like so:   var stream = fs.createReadStream('dog.jpeg', {
                highWaterMark:5
            });           but if there is a better way please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.read()`:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt', options);
var byteSize = 10;

stream.on("readable", function() {
    var chunk;
    while ( (chunk = stream.read(byteSize)) ) {
        console.log(chunk.length);
    }
});
```

The main benefit of knowing this one over just the `highWaterMark` option is that you can call it on streams you haven't created.

[Here are the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size)